# Disable use of 'any' in Ts project?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript, tsconfig

Making a React Native app with expo/typescript and since I'm working in a team I want to disable use of type:any since it happened a couple of times someone puts it and forgets to remove it and it doesn't end well usually

```json
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
  },
}

This is my current tsconfig.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the [`no-explicit-any`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-explicit-any/) from `typescript-eslint` !

The basic ts setting doesn't have that option.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript itself doesn't have a setting for that, but [`typescript-eslint`](https://typescript-eslint.io) has one: [`no-explicit-any`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-explicit-any).